# How can an object be equal to an empty string?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I was playing around with the Google Apps Script API when I noticed this interesting detail, as outlined in the following code

```
function testEmptyRange() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  Logger.log(values.length + " " + values[0].length);
  Logger.log((values[0][0] == "") + " " + typeof values[0][0]);
  Logger.log((values[0] == "") + " " + typeof values[0]);
  Logger.log((values == "") + " " + typeof values);
}
```

If `Sheet1` has no content whatsoever, then `values` is a [1-by-1 2D array of Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues), effectively a single cell containing an empty string. What really surprised me is the fact that *both* `values` *and* `values[0]`, which are type `object`, are also equal to the empty string. The log produced by the above function is

```
[17-03-05 00:43:46:807 EST] 1 1
[17-03-05 00:43:46:807 EST] true string
[17-03-05 00:43:46:808 EST] true object
[17-03-05 00:43:46:808 EST] true object
```

I would like an explanation as to why this is the case. How can an object be equal to the empty string? I realize that the operator `==` is different from the operator `===`, and that if I were to replace the former with the latter, then the log shows `false` for both `values` and `values[0]`, which is more along the lines of expected behavior, I suppose. But that doesn't explain why or how an object can equal an empty string in the first case, and I would like to understand what's going on here.

Comment: Javascript has [automatic type conversion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Loose_equality_using).  It's a cute feature that allows some clever behavior, but it also means that you can get into trouble when you don't know what to expect.  This is especially confusing for equality comparisons, which is why `==` comparison is discouraged in favor of strict `===` comparison, which disallows any automatic type conversion.  As for your scenario, even w/ type conversion `{} == ''` should be `false`; are you sure it wasn't `[] == ''`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, as you mentioned, that `==` does not represent the strictest kind of comparison. `==` uses type coercion of its arguments in an often failed attempt to be more helpful to us programmers.

When one argument of `==` is of type string, the other is *always* casted to a string before the two values are compared. Thus, for an object, the JavaScript engine ends up doing something like this:

1. `object == ""`
2. `String(object) === ""`
3. `object.toString() === ""`

Since an object can have any `toString` method you give it, the output of this comparison could potentially be `true`.

**Edit:** Looking at [anied](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6831341/anied)'s comment above and re-reading your example code, it hit me that `values` and `values[0]` are actually **arrays**, which are a special case of the object type. They have a `toString` method that joins together all array elements with commas, which means that an empty array `[]` will be stringified into `""`

### Examples:

```js
var object = {
  toString: function () { return '' }
}

console.log(typeof object) //=> 'object'
console.log(object == "") //=> true


var array = []

console.log(typeof array) //=> 'object'
console.log(array == "") //=> true


var matrix = [
  ['']
]

console.log(typeof matrix) //=> 'object'
console.log(matrix == "") //=> true
```